# Java static constant class variable assignment

Tags: java, variable-assignment, static-members

I'm creating a Vector2 class in Java, and have an issue:

```
public class Vector2 {
    public static final Vector2 ZERO = new Vector2(0,0);
    ...
}
```

in another class, I'd like to call ZERO like this:

```
Vector2 myVector = Vector2.ZERO; //initialize to zero
myVector.add(myOtherVector); //myVector is now the sum of Vector2.ZERO and myOtherVector
```

However, this behaves undesirably: myVector just becomes Vector2.ZERO--and thus unchangeable--rather than being initialized to the zero value and then being free to work with as I wish. To get the behavior I want, I need:

```
Vector2 myVector = new Vector2(Vector2.Zero); //initialize to zero with copy constructor
```

I'm a little confused by Java's semantics here (i.e someVector essentially seems to be a pointer rather than an actual object, so I have to create a new object and explicity copy the values.) After reading up on that, I understand there's a lot of confusion on that topic. Is there a simple way to achieve the syntax I'm looking for or should I just stick with option 2? If there isn't, is there a way to prevent the assignment in option 1? It's going to give me some hard to catch errors later if I don't stop it at compile time.

Edit: Vector2 isn't immutable. What I'd like is for Vector2.ZERO to be a constant value I can use for assignments, but then manipulate those new variables normally. Right now if I do that assignment in multiple places, then all of those are just pointers to the same object (which because it's static just accumulates the changes).

For example, in Unity when working with vectors I would say something like:

```
Vector2 myFirstVector = Vector2.ZERO; //first vector, initialized to zero
...//do some stuff to change the value of myFirstVector, Vector2.ZERO unchanged


Vector2 mySecondVector = Vector2.ZERO; //second vector, also initialized to zero
...//do some stuff to mySecondVector
```

Comment: What is Vector2? Is it immutable?

Comment: It is "Java" and not "JAVA"

Comment: unlike C++, in Java there are only references to objects. This applies to all non-primitive types.

Comment: Vector2 (the class itself) isn't immutable, but the member vector2 should be constant. I'm going to update the question to be a bit more clear.

Comment: If there are any suggestions for clarifying the question for any future readers, please let me know. I'm not 100% on SO etiquette on editing questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your vectors to be mutable, having a static field that holds the zero vector is not a good choice (since it can mutate to something else later.

There are two approaches that you can take:
**Mutable Vectors**

```
public class Vector2 {
    public static Vector2 Zero() {
         return new Vector2(0,0);
    }
}
```

**Immutable vectors**

```
public class Vector2 {

  public static final Vector2 ZERO = new Vector2(0, 0);

  private final int x;
  private final int y;

  public Vector2(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  public Vector2 add(Vector2 v) {
    return new Vector2(this.x + v.x, this.y +v.y);
  }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. This is the same thing as it is done in BigInteger, BigDecimal, and the like.

Comment: Accepted because now that I look at it, I'll probably be better off making it immutable as multiple answers and comments have suggested. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to create a static factory method to return a new Vector that is Zeroed.

```
public class Vector2 {
    public static Vector2 Zero() {
         return new Vector2(0,0);
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
Vector2 myVector = Vector2.Zero();
```

Of course, if your default constructor initializes the vector to 0,0, then you may not need this and can simply do:  `Vector2 myVector = new Vector2();`

Your initial thought about: "However, this behaves undesirably: myVector just becomes Vector2.ZERO--and thus unchangeable--" is incorrect unless Vector2 is immutable.  You won't be able to reassign anything else to Vector2.ZERO, but you can certainly modify the object's contents.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I should have thought of that.

Yeah, I was wrong about the immutability. I saw undesirable behavior in drawing objects using the vector math and thought it was because they were stuck at (0,0) when they were actually accumulating changes from all the assignments.

Answer (score 1):

Make your class [*immutable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), so `add()` would return a new instance rather than modifying the instance, then:

```
myInstance = myInstance.add(myOtherVector);
```

See [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) for a class from the JDK that works like this.

Answer (score 0):

That is the whole point of OOP and object references.

```
Vector2 myVector = Vector2.ZERO;
```

means that your `myVector` variable will reference to the same object (in memory) as static field `Vector2.ZERO` does. Basicly it is reffering the same object in memory.

You wrote:

> someVector essentially seems to be a pointer

well, that is preatty it. References can be understood as pointers to objects just as pointers to defined memory address in C.